# ICMP traffic limit on Google Cloud Plataform

Tags: icmp

A few weeks ago we realized that there are losses of ICMP packets sent/received between the networks of the telecommunications operator Telefonica / Vivo from Brazil and the IP addresses of Google in the United States (US Central).
We have a server (vm) monitoring our services on Google Cloud Plataform and facing issues of false positives and service failures.
We talked to Telefonica / Vivo in Brazil and they told us that this is a limitation imposed by Google for this type of traffic with this operator.
Is there any collaborator in the group having this difficulty either, or do you know how we can trigger Google to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you really have a need to send large amounts of ICMP traffic?!

Comment: Yes, we have a Zabbix Server in GCP to check the status and collect metrics of links and devices with public IP, and one of the checks is a ICMP ping.

Comment: Have you considered running a Zabbix proxy in the USA?